# From equivalence relation to function

Tags: functions, equivalence-relations

I need your help with the following task:
I have to prove:

If $ \sim $ is an equivalence relation on a set $ A $ and if $ C=\{[a ]_\sim \mid a \in A\} $ is the set of equivalence classes of $ \sim $, then there is a function $ p: A \longrightarrow C $ such that for all $ a_{1}, a_{2} \in A : a_{1} \sim a_{2} \Longleftrightarrow p\left(a_{1}\right)=p\left(a_{2}\right)$

Comment: You should show your efforts first. Think is there a natural way to associate element of $A$ with an element in $C$

Comment: Since p is a function, because for each a from A there is an one [a]~ from C.

Therefore one have to show hat p has the property

a1 ~ a2 equivalent to p(a1) = p(a2) for all a1, a2 from A.

If I take now a1 and a2  put them into p then I get:

a1 ~ a2 equivalent to [[a1]] ~ = [[a2]]~

But I don't know how this helps me to prove the statement.

Comment: Have you considered, say, $p(a)=[a]_{\sim}$?

Comment: I feel kind of stupid=) How do you mean that

Comment: The function which maps each element in $A$ to its equivalence class